# Is sum of two asymptotically normal variables still asymptotically normal?

Tags: statistics, asymptotics, normal-distribution, central-limit-theorem

Suppose $X_n$ and $Y_n$ are two sequences of random variables, satisfying that
$\sqrt{n}(X_n - X)$ and $\sqrt{n}(Y_n - Y)$ both converge to two normal distribution with mean $0$.
Will $\sqrt{n}\{(X_n + Y_n) - (X+Y)\}$ converge to normal distribution?

If not, given the facts that $cov(\sqrt{n}(X_n - X), \sqrt{n}(Y_n - Y))\to 0$, can we derive normal for their sum? And if this condition doesn't work, what condition will we need?

I try to prove it using Delta method, that if
$$\sqrt{n}(X_n - X, Y_n - Y)^{T}\to Normal((0,0)^{T}, \Sigma),$$
we have $f(X_n, Y_n)$ converges to normal with mean $f(X,Y)$. Is there anything wrong when using Delta method for some counter examples?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Take $Y_n=-X_n, Y=-X$ for a counter-example.

Comment: This isn't a counterexample! It would converge to the degenerate normal distribution $N(0,0)$.

Comment: However, if you assume that $\sqrt{n}(X_n-X,Y_n-Y)^T \to N((0,0)^T,\Sigma)$, then (by definition) $\sqrt{n}\big(X_n-X+Y_n-Y\big) \to N(0,Tr(\Sigma^2))$